# getting Error permission denied while changes github action server

Tags: linux, path, devops, github-actions, cicd

sftp> put -r ./dist/* /var/www/project_1
Entering ./dist/assets/
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory

```
remote open("/var/www/project_1/common.js"): Permission denied
.

.

.
```

This error has been seen after updating the deployment server in the GitHub action (along with the server key, IP address, and deployment path[/var/www/project_1/] ).
The project 1 deployment route in the server has already been set up.

The GitHub action for the deployment server functioned properly prior to the change.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, it is usually necessary to verify that the server's existing users, such as **root** or **Ubuntu**, do not have access to this folder before issuing the command to **grant permission**.

```
$ sudo chown $USER /var/www/project_1
```